# Python Imports - Reference Top Level Module Instead of the "In-Level" Module

Tags: python, django

Python v2.7

**Directory Structure**:

```
- project
  - manage.py
  - utils
    - __init__.py
    - somescript.py
  - apps
    - __init__.py
    - someapp
      - views.py
      - utils.py
```

**project.apps.someapp.views**:

```
// imports
from utils import somescript

// rest of the stuff
```

Raises `ImportError: cannot import name somescript`

Tried a dotted relative import:

```
// imports

from ...utils import somescript

// rest of the stuff
```

This raises `ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package`.

This is a Django project. It runs through `manage.py`.
**Command**:  `./manage.py runserver 0:41000`

Comment: I'd put `utils` into `apps`. Then you can do: `from ..utils import somescript`.

Comment: Using more than two dots `..` for relative imports is frowned upon.

Comment: manage.py puts the project directory on the pythonpath, so `from utils import somescript` should work. What is the exact error and traceback you get? Could there be a circular import issue?

Comment: @cezar I cannot move any modules from here to there. I have a simple solution to rename `apps.someapp.utils` to `apps.someapp.some_utils`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman exactly that's what I thought. There are no circular imports. The same line `from utils import somescript` works in other apps where I don't have any `utils` module in those apps.

Comment: Sorry, yes I hadn't noticed the problem was with the extra utils in the app. The solution as you say is to rename that. Or, better, upgrade to Python 3 where implicit relative imports are removed; honestly, you should upgrade anyway.

Comment: @DanielRoseman why rename anything ? python 2.7 supports absolute imports (with the `__future__` lib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit suprised someone like Daniel Roseman advise you to rename one of your modules when this issue has long been solved by providing support for absolute imports in py2 via the `__future__` lib.

All you need is to add this at the top of your module (before any other statement):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

From there on, all non explicitely relative imports will be treated as absolute (ie as in py3), so in apps.someapp.views, you can do:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import utils # => project.utils
from . import utils as local_utils # => apps.someapp.utils
```

NB: note that `__future__` directives only affect the current module, your other modules will remain unaffected.

NB2: you may want to have a look at `__future__.unicode_literals` too - it makes life much easier in django projects which mostly expect unicode everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel Roseman suggested you should upgrade to Python 3.

However this isn't always possible, or at least not possible right now.

There is a Python built-in module [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/imp.html). You can use it to manually import the files you need.

Here is an example how it could work:

**`project.apps.someapp.views`**

```
import imp
somescript = imp.load_source('utils.somescript', 'path/to/utils/somescript.py')
```

Now you can use `somescript` in your `views.py`. It's not the nicest solution, but it might help you to bridge the gap until you're ready to upgrade your codebase to Python 3.

Also please take care to specify the filepath in a flexible way, without hard coding.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers can you give an example/source explaining how that will work?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Nothing is wrong with `__future__.absolute_imports`. I didn't know it till now, but now I know it, thanks to you.